# How to define a non-uniform mangetic field in Geant$4$ simulation?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, computational-physics, simulations, software

I am getting stuck in creating a gradient magnetic field by the Fieldmap method in the example of field$04$ (geant$4$/extend/field/field$04$).
At the moment, I am doing OK with creating a uniform one by creating a field vector in example field$03$. However, when containing a gradient field functioning $B_z = a\cdot\mathrm{abs}(z) +b$ into a solenoid tube-shaped absorber (whereas $B_x=B_y=0$), it compiles a gradient field cover by half of the World Volume.

My detector construction basically is as following:

- World: a box with its origin $(0,0,0)$.
- Absorber: a tube with its $X,Y,Z$ position relative to the World, applied a symmetric gradient $Z$ field (symmetric point is its $Z$ position) to the whole absorber with the above function.

Comment: You can find the answer in this slide. http://geant4.in2p3.fr/2007/prog/JohnApostolakis/EMField.pdf